# understanding floats better in CSS

Tags: css

I have the following 3 divs (a left center and right). Its behaving exactly as i expected it to:

```
         #leftPane,#rightPane,{
         width: 250px;
         height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid blue;

           }
        #centerPane {
      height: 200px;

               }
            #leftPane {
                  float: left;
                }
               #rightPane {
                 float: right;
              }
```

This is my html:

```
          <div id="leftPane">Left Pane</div>
            <div id="rightPane">Right Pane</div>
          <div id="centerPane">Center Pane</div>
```

I wanted to have the center div have an adjustable width because i'm going to have to left and right panes collapsible. Notice the text 'Center pane' is 250px from the left. This is what i wanted, but now I want to add padding, background color etc, yet i add this to my html:

```
      <div id="centerPane"><div style="background:#cccccc;">Center Pane</div></div>
```

I thought the gray background color would only be around the 'Center text' but it goes all the way across the width of the screen. So i'm confused as to why the text of centerPane is behaving correctly but any styles added to the center div is going across the width of the screen. Can anyone show me how to style the centerPane content between the left and right pane divs? Thank you

Comment: Don't forget to remove this extra comma: `#leftPane,#rightPane,{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `float: left` on the center div also. What is happening is the left and right divs are out of the document flow (they don't affect anything else), so the center div is taking up the same area. If you use `clear:both` on the center, it will go beneath the left and right, as this fixes the document flow. Since you want the center to be in the center, you'll need to float it left also so that it goes next to the left div.

`overflow: hidden` will fix the background in this case, but the layout is awkward - especially when the window is smaller (see what happens to the center div). I would use `display:table-cell` as in my answer below.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AxoQEZi/1/edit)**

You may also be interested in `display: inline-block` and `display: table-cell`

#### Display table-cell

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="leftPane">Left Pane</div>
  <div id="centerPane">Center Pane</div>
  <div id="rightPane">Right Pane</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.container div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 250px;
}
#centerPane { 
  background: #ccc;
  width: auto;
}
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AxoQEZi/3/edit)**

Comment: Hello m59...thanks for responding. The reason I dont float the center div is i want the width to take up the rest of the screen. So my right and left divs are 250px apiece and if the users screen is 1000px in width, i want centerPane to be 500px automatically.

Comment: @BoundForGlory I would use `display: table-cell` for this kind of layout. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

overflow:hidden; will contain the background.

```
<div id="centerPane"><div style="background:#cccccc;overflow:hidden">Center Pane</div></div>
```

Comment: This is what i was missing. Thank you

Comment: Good catch! @BoundForGlory Also note that the layout still behaves oddly when window is smaller. You might want to highly consider `display: table-cell`.

Comment: @m59 Ya, I'm migrating away from floats toward display:inline-block and display: table-cell. IE8 supports both.